# Django is searching wrong statics directory

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, django-staticfiles

When i run django on uwsgi with;

> uwsgi --http :8081 --module proj1.wsgi

It gives below error when i open start page from browser:

> Not Found: /accounts/login/static/css/style.css

But my settings.py is :

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/proj1/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/proj1/staticorj/static/',
)
```

When i make collectstatic, it copies files to static root without problem.
I dont understand why does it look for /accounts/login.
It should look in /home/proj1 directory for static dir.
So the browser opens the page but without serving static files.

Comment: Django won't serve static files in a production setup, you must use a webserver in front of it. [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) and [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) docs.

Comment: Although spectras is correct, that is not the actual problem here. In fact the issue doesn't have anything to do with the code you have posted. Presumably in your template you are using a relative path to reference the static files instead of an absolute one. You need to post that template.

Comment: I use,  {% load staticfiles %}
    <!-- CSS -->
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'css/animate.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        ...

Comment: If i change the settings.py to below conf. It begins to show the page and read css files. But this time it does not show images  in styles.css    >>>> STATIC_URL = '/home/proj1/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/proj1/staticorj/static/',
)

Answer (score 0):

Statics operation should be like this.
First configure settings.py like below :

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/proj1/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/proj1/staticorj/static/',
)
```

Put statics files that you need in /home/proj1/staticorj/static/
Then run :

> python manage.py collectstatic

This will carry /home/proj1/staticorj/static/ files to /home/proj1/static/ directory, and now django will use /home/proj1/static/ directory for static source.

If you will not make any statics changes set as below with commenting.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATIC_ROOT = '/home/proj1/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#    '/home/proj1/staticorj/static/',
#)
```

And run your server. Better use uwsgi and nginx like apps to serv. In production files will be served. Also use new version browser.